# SharePoint 2010 MUI doesn't work with Office 2007 templates?

Tags: 2010, document-template, office, multilingual

MUI is active and working, however when the office document templates retrieves the list fields names, they're retrieved with the List/Web based language and not the user context language.

Is that a version limitation [SharePoint 2010 with Office 2007] or a SharePoint limitation? If it is a limitation what the best way to go for workaround this (huge) limitation?

Note: I've found [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384150%28v=office.14%29.aspx) white paper comparing Office version and their differences but in any case MUI support is referenced.

Note 2: [Tech net documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805062.aspx#Section7) about MUI Limitations, however no reference to the document templates information panel fields.